# Odd error: local variables cannot be used before being defined. But I did defined it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
public partial class introduction : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static BusinessService bs = null;
        private static List<PCUser> coaches = new List<PCUser>();
.............

 public void BindRepeater()
        {
            if (coaches == null || coaches.Count == 0)
            { 

            }
```

The compiler complains of the coaches in the BindRepeater.

Error message:
 Local variables cannot be used before being defined.

But if I use the coaches like this :

```
introduction.coaches
```

Then the error will go.

Interestingly, I can use bs directly without referring the introduction.

Can anyone tell me the reason for this error?

For me, I think bs and coaches are at the same access level, thus both of them should be able to be accessed directly by referring their names.

**PS: 
Another question, will the content of the variable coaches still exist after the whole web page is refreshed? Coz I have to use it to do the pagination.**

Comment: Maybe there is another variable named `coaches`, which took priority in your scope.

Comment: @YoryeNathan ,Ooooops. you are right >_<; thx mate. another one, will he content of the variable coaches still exist after the whole web page is refreshed? Coz I have to use it to do the pagination.

Comment: @YoryeNathan can you reply this question as an answer? so I can set your reply as the right one.

Comment: @Franva: Yes, since it's static, but that variable is also shared by every request to that page by every user of the site.  The recommended way to preserve data for a postback is to put it in ViewState (or maybe session, or a GUID in ViewState that's an index into a static dictionary), not a static variable.

Comment: @YoryeNathan thank you for your ideas! could you please post your as an answer so I can set your reply as the answer. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is another variable named coaches, which took priority in your scope.

I suggest using different names, and having [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to warn you about name collisions.

Comment: Yes, I did have another variable which has the same name. But I didn't get any warning about name collision. It's strange....

Comment: oh I thought it's the BindRepeater() method, sorry I didn't see it carefully haha